# On ButtonClick backgroundcolor of various Tablecells

Tags: java, html, css, background, tablecell

I need a little help with Java here. How do I fill e.g. table cell 4,3, and 16 by clicking a Button ?

So If I click my Button I want the predefined tablecells to be red. Sorry but I'm a beginner.

Hope someone can help me :-)

cheers and stay healthy

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.fill {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="">CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your question, I am going to assume that it is related to Javascript and not Java. If not and you really needed a helping hand in Java, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding!

So, first I think you need to add some ids to your tablecells, so we can identify them later.

Then you call a small Javascript function when you click the button with just a parameter, an array of the tablecells' ids that you want to color.

That function, for each id that you provide, will add the class fill.

I hope that answers your question, sorry for my English and my technique, I'm a kind of beginner too!

```js
function fill_cells($cells) {
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('fill'));
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.fill {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        <td id="11">12</td>
        <td id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="13">13</td>
        <td id="14">14</td>
        <td id="15">15</td>
        <td id="16">16</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="fill_cells([4, 3, 16])">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly, but now I have the next problem :-D

I want a Button that f.e. does fill_cells([1,2,3,4]) and another button, that fills_cells([5,6,7]), but when I click the second Button, the table cells 1,2,3,4 return to bGcolor transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert either on this, but you could use JQuery to change css, see https://api.jquery.com/css/

```js
function makeRed() {
   $(".selected").css("background-color", "red");
  }
```

```css
table td {
      border: 1 px solid black;
      padding: 30 px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
            <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class='selected'>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button onclick=makeRed()>CLICK</button>
```